# How to link external url with button in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui

I'm pretty new to Material-UI and testing my web-app with localhost. Basically, I have created a button that will route to external url ([www.google.ca](http://www.google.ca) for now) when the user clicks on it. For unknown reason, clicking a button routes to http://localhost:3001/www.google.ca instead of https://www.google.ca. Not sure what the problem is?

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

import waterBottle from '../images/tom.jpg';

// All the code has been retrieved from https://material-ui.com/components/cards/#card
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MembersInfo() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={waterBottle}
          title="Image"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Tom Wong
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
           Tom is a business administrative student at xxx university.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        
            <Button size="small" color="primary" href="www.google.ca" target="_blank" to = "/url">
            Google
            </Button>
        
       
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: try to use anchor(<a />) instead of <Link> inside your Button component

Comment: It appears that the Button's `href` prop is only used to append a hash (`#123`) to the URL: `http://localhost:3000/abc#123`.  As mentioned in the comment above, you should just wrap the Button with an HTMLAnchor tag (`<a>...</a>`) and append the href and target to it.

Comment: So I tried it with the following: <a href = "www.google.ca" target="_blank">
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
                LinkedIn
            </Button>
        </a>
But it seems like it's still routing to http://localhost:3000/abc#123

Comment: Just make sure you remove the link props from the Button: [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/link-material-button-r3j4v)

Comment: You need to specify the "https://" part otherwise the browser interprets it as a relative URL.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone runs across this issue with using the Link component from Material UI - a few comments addressed some of the issues.

Additionally, make sure you're importing the Link correctly from material ui since they've updated their API. I tried using the API provided ('@mui/material/Link') but had to use their old API (@material-ui/core/Link) for it to work.

If the import is correct, this is the the code that will open up a new tab to google while you're developing using localhost:

```
<Link target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer">
View Link
</Link>
```